# Can a user at the linux shell check whether sd_watchdog is enabled?

Tags: linux, servicemanager

Is there a way to check from the command line whether the service manager expects. watchdog keep-alive notifications from a service; as in a command that makes this check:

https://arcticfox1919.gitee.io/linux-manual/man-pages/man3/sd_watchdog_enabled.3.html